# Internet connections work on Linux Mint system, but Intranet connections fail

Tags: linux, dns, linux-mint, lan

As the title states everything is working fine but when I try to connect to any of our Intranet servers I get “server cannot be found.” If I put the IP address of the server in the browser it connects right away.

This is a bit of a pain for me because we have several Intranet servers and so I end up doing an `nslookup` to find out what the IP is and then typing that in the browser.

- My `eth0` is set to get IP via DHCP
- `nslookup` for the Intranet site shows correct IP searching by name
- `nslookup` shows correct name if I search by IP.
- Doesn’t matter which browser I use, Mozilla, Chrome or Opera.

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep hosts`.

Comment: cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep hosts returns
hosts: files mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns